# Working with multiple workbooks in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I have been working on excel 2010. There was a feature that when I worked on more than one workbook, all workbooks were shown stacked side by side below in the main window of excel, and I can minimize, restore or close any of the workbook without closing the main excel window. Always two set of (minimize, restore, close) tabs were seen on the top, one set for main excel window and second for the active workbook. Can this feature be used in excel 2013. Please help it was very helping and useful feature.

Comment: This feature still exists.  Works exactly like it did in Office 2010

Comment: But how? Kindly explain.

Answer (score 2):

Excel 2013 does the very handy thing of opening all your workbooks up in seperate instances, that are still properly connected, much like Word always did.

Because the various workooks aren't stored in the same instance you won't be able to do exactly what you're after (viewing them all in the single instance pane) but you can tile them however you like to view them side by side.

Windows 7 and above allows you to press Windows+[ArrowKey] to push windows to the top, bottom or either side of a screen, but Excel also allows you to tile your Excel instances much like before: under View, go to the Window group and use the Arrange function (you may also want to play around with the Split function)

[image: The View Tab's Window Group]