# Closing workbook in Excel 2013 without closing the Excel window

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Further question related to topic: [Working with multiple workbooks in Excel 2013](https://superuser.com/questions/686348/working-with-multiple-workbooks-in-excel-2013)

The functionality of Excel 2013 where closing a workbook closes the whole Excel 2013 window is quite annoying. Closing the window completely used to be able by clicking on the X of that window. If one wants to close only the workbook one could click on the X of the window of the particular workbook. Now there is no choice anymore.

The reasons that I find this annoying are:

1. I often have two or more Excel windows open in two separate (physical) screens. If I wanted to close a workbook in one of the screens and immediately open a new workbook I would just close the workbook. The Excel window would stay and I could immediately open a new workbook.

Now I have to first open a new workbook, then go back to the one I want to close and close it. If you are going through a couple of files that's an annoying extra step.

If you do close the open workbook first and then open a new Excel window - to be able to open a new file - you have no control over which screen the window will be shown. Furthermore, after you open a new Excel window and open a file it will keep the blank workbook that Excel automatically shows. So you would still end up with a workbook you don't need and need to close separately.

2. In previous versions of Excel the last open or save location would be retained per window. In the new Excel 2013 the last open or save location of any open workbook is the location that is shown upon clicking the open workbook button. So one has to navigate folders all the time if you have several locations where files are stored.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know it is an old post but so many struggle with this: 
Use Control-W (Close Workbook); or File, Close; or the new ribbon inspired shortcut would be: ALT+F, C. Then S to Save or N to Not Save.